# How to Bring Products in homepage?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am Creating a magento pages and i have imported 20 Products. but i cant able to show the products in homepage.

The following Way i had tried but failed.

> {{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
>
> {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

after tried the above methods there is an Error appeared

> no products Matching

So kindly help me out. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure the products are enabled, in stock and have visibility `catalog` or `catalog & search`.

Then, I see you are using the `new products` block.
This may not work as you expect it to work. It displays the products that have the `New from date` and/or `New to date` field filled in with a date that would make them `new` today.

So if neither of these fields are filled in the product is not considered new.